# Update DataGrid for multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I'm populating a gridview with results from multiple tables. My question is how can I write the stored procedure to update multiple tables at once. I'm capturing the values in variables like you see below, so now do I just have to pass them to a sp to update database and gridview?

```
protected void gvOrderDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
        int key = Convert.ToInt32(gvOrderDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

        TextBox TrackingID = (TextBox)(gvOrderDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditTrackingID"));
        TextBox OrderDate = (TextBox)(gvOrderDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditOrderDate"));
        TextBox CustID = (TextBox)(gvOrderDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditCustID"));
        TextBox CustomerName = (TextBox)(gvOrderDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditCustName"));
        TextBox Address = (TextBox)(gvOrderDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditAddress"));
        TextBox RouteID = (TextBox)(gvOrderDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditRouteID"));
        // reset to original view
        gvOrderDetails.EditIndex = -1;
        //Databind
        GrabandPostData();
    }
```

edit: using sql server 2012

Comment: What are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle...?

Comment: I am using Sql Server

Comment: And what is the table name, the database name, the column(s) in particular that you want to update? What's the name of the primary column in the table?

Comment: Gridview has already been updated (since RowUpdating is firing) you just need to update tables in DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure can have multiple update/insert statements, so once you captured your parameters, you can pass them to your SP and it will act accordingly to the logic you put into it, e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTablesUpdate(@TrackingID int, @OrderDate datetime, @CustID int, @CustomerName varchar(250)) 
AS
BEGIN
     UPDATE ORDERS SET OrderDate = @OrderDate WHERE TrackingID = @TrackingID 

     UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET CustomerName = @CustomerName WHERE CustID = @CustID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure and pass all the values as parameters. Then in the Stored Procedure write two update statements to update the two different tables.